# Adding decimal after whole number in Lua

Tags: ios, lua, integer, coronasdk

I am trying to make a decimal number counter in Lua (CoronaSDK), however am having issues with whole numbers.

Each time the user presses a button, .1 is added to the score.  Once the user hits a whole number, it defaults back to a whole number, 1.

The counter is working fine, however, I would like to make it so that once a whole number is hit a .0 is added to the end of the number.

For example,

```
0.0 (right now it is just 0)
0.1,
0.2,
0.3,
0.4,
...
0.9,
1.0 (right now it is just 1)
1.1,
...
2.0 (right now it is just 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what string formatting is for

```
print(string.format("%.1f", 1))
```

prints

```
1.0
```

and in general

```
for i = 0, 2.1, 0.1 do
  print(string.format("%.1f", i))
end
```

gives you

```
0.0
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.8
0.9
1.0
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.4
1.5
1.6
1.7
1.8
1.9
2.0
```